# Parsing xlsx file in ruby using gem roo

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My HTML code, here am passing xslx file for parsing,

```
<form method="post" action="/home/parse_xlsx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Upload XSLX File <input type="file" name="xlsx_file" id="xlsx_file"  />
   <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

My Controller code,

```
def parse_xlsx
    xlsxFile = params[:xlsx_file]
    prefix_tmp_path = xlsxFile.path
    filename = xlsxFile.original_filename
    fullname = File.join(prefix_tmp_path,filename) 

    require 'roo'
    s = Roo::Excelx.new(fullname)

    for i in 1..14
      puts s.cell(i,3) 
    end
end
```

Giving me error ,

```
file /tmp/RackMultipart20130910-10043-u4nqsc/CMS.xlsx does not exist
```

When I run the following code on console am keeping my 'CMS.xlsx' file in rails root folder & it is running without any errors.

```
require 'roo'
s = Roo::Excelx.new("CMS.xlsx")
for i in 1..14
  puts s.cell(i,3) 
end
```

Please explain where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

xlsxFile.path is the file's location, you shouldn't have to join in the filename.  If you need to save the file, you can rename it the original filename when you move it to it's file location

try

```
 s = Roo::Excelx.new(xlsxFile.path)
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this but by this way it is giving me error that no such file in tmp

Comment: if you look in your tmp after uploading, what do you see there?